# Magento2 Payment Methods admin dumping out php info broken page

Tags: magento-2.3

So had a weird error with Magento2.

When viewing the Payment Methods screen in admin after an upgrade to 2.3 it is outputting a seemingly broken PHP Info page.

Amazon_Core/js/simplepath

Then it was an output of the phpinfo page.

I disabled the phpinfo method in my php fpm ini and restarted php7.1-fpm service.
After this I was able to load the page and saw Klarna amazon pay

[image]

Well I don't need amazon pay.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the modules to remove the Amazon Payment Method.

```
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Login
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Payment
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core
bin/magento module:disable Klarna_Kp
bin/magento module:disable Klarna_Ordermanagement
bin/magento module:disable Klarna_Core
```

Rebuild All

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:flush
```